# Javascript to PHP email validation?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex, validation

So I'm working on an application where Javascript will first validate the email using a regex and then once sent to PHP, PHP will verify the user did not modify any of the javascript and validate the info again with `filter_var`.

For example, in JS I validate with this regex first using `.test()`

> `/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/`

This is a regex I picked up off emailregex.com and seems to validate everything fairly well.

After the form is submitted I use php `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` to once again validate.

Does this method have any downsides and would there be any better ways to do this?

Comment: You should include the rest of the code that does this work, as it is there is not enough code present to meaningfully review properly.

Comment: You will find some usefull informations about email addresses here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples

Comment: [mpyw/FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL.js: JavaScript Email validation compatible with PHP's filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)](https://github.com/mpyw/FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL.js#readme)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Client-side** validation is for **user convenience** and, marginally, to reduce load on your server... the user will be notified more quickly of an error, speeding up the process of correcting it, and the user's computer handles the processing.

**Server-side** validation is for **security and safety**, because you can't trust the client. Users can disable or disrupt JavaScript (sometimes by accident), or they can use tools like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to fake HTTP requests.

Sounds like you are doing things correctly.

One downside that comes to mind immediately is when your **client-side and server-side validation don't match**. For example, if your client-side validation is stricter (accidentally), you could end up with a scenario where things look secure but are actually vulnerable to HTTP request hacking. This can be mitigated with lots and lots of automated testing of both the client-side and server-side services.

Another downside is code replication. Keeping both the **client and server up-to-date and in sync** with ever-changing requirements can be tedious and error prone, and sometimes server-side and client-side technologies aren't exactly one-for-one, making it **difficult to engineer identical solutions**. Once again, lots of automated testing can mitigate errors and ensure that both client and server are in sync.

Comment: I ended up using the same regex on both the client and backend this way it will have no confusion. A bit of an off topic question but when would be a good time to use `htmlspecialchars`?

Comment: The regex may be the same, but that doesn't mean that that the regex parsers are the same. While I think that you are safe with this particular regex, keep in mind that regexes in [PHP and JS are different](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1131918/211627). Nothing can replace a good test suite.